# Passing the elements of a vector to a different data structure by address

Tags: c++, pointers, quadtree

I am building a 2d game and I am storing all my enemy objects in an array. Right now I am trying to implement a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Currently I am just trying to build the quadtree and am not concerned with collisions. The code that pushes items to the quadtree is the following :

```
for (std::vector<Enemy>::iterator i=m_enemies.begin(); i != m_enemies.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << &(*i) << "Address of the object" << std::endl;
    m_quad.Insert(&(*i));
}
```

The code for the Insert is the following :

```
void Quad::Insert(sf::RectangleShape* l_gameObject){
    std::cout << &l_gameObject << "dsa1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "called insert " << m_objects.size() << std::endl;
    m_objects.push_back(l_gameObject);
    if (m_level < m_maxLevel) {
        if (m_objects.size() > 3) {
            std::cout<< "creating subregions " << m_objects.size() << std::endl;
            m_subRegions.push_back(Quad(m_x,m_y,m_width/2.f, m_height/2, m_level + 1, m_maxLevel-1));
            m_subRegions.push_back(Quad(m_x+m_width/2.f,m_y,m_width/2.f,m_height/2.f, m_level + 1, m_maxLevel-1));
            m_subRegions.push_back(Quad(m_x+m_width/2.f, m_y + m_height/2.f, m_width/2.f, m_height/2.f, m_level + 1, m_maxLevel-1));
            m_subRegions.push_back(Quad(m_x, m_y + m_height/2.f, m_width/2.f, m_height/2.f, m_level + 1, m_maxLevel-1));
            std::vector<int> temp;
            for (int i=0; i < m_objects.size(); i++){
                for (int j=0; j< m_subRegions.size(); j++) {
                    if (m_subRegions[j].Contains(m_objects[i])) {
                        m_subRegions[j].Insert(m_objects[i]);
                        temp.push_back(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = temp.size(); i > -1; i--){
                m_objects.erase(m_objects.begin() + temp[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I print the address that I am passing **to** the Insert function and the one I have **in** the function I see that they are different. In fact the on **in** is always the same and the one I pass is always different as it should be. Could anyone clarify why that is the case ?

EDIT : Thanks to gsamaras for pointing out that I was printing the address of the parameter.

**Followup question**

When I use the methods of the object I am addressing in the first for loop I get the correct results, but when I do the same thing in the Insert function I  get 0. Why is that ?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was printing the address of the address. Could you check the edit for the second problem I am having ?

Comment: Well I posted an answer, with more clear code than the one I commented before (that's why I deleted that comment), and this answers your question. I am not sure what you mean with the followup question. In general, a posted question should ask one thing though..

Comment: This might be no issue in your case but, please, be aware that addresses of `std::vector` elements _can_ become invalid if you insert (or push-back) new elements (as this might cause a re-allocation of the internal buffer).

Comment: You are completely right, but it is not an issue for now. First I want to figure out the pushing and then I will implement the cleaning when removing an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the address of the address.

Change this:

```
std::cout << &l_gameObject << "dsa1" << std::endl;
```

to this:

```
std::cout << l_gameObject << "dsa1" << std::endl;
```

in order to print the same thing as outside your of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Insert`, you're printing the address of the parameter.
Outside `Insert`, you're printing the parameter's value.

You want

```
std::cout << l_gameObject << "dsa1" << std::endl;
```

since `l_gameObject` is the address you're passing in.